# Row updating is not done

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

When the Grid view shows the data & when i click on the name it will go for Row Updateing event of the Grid view.All text box are updated but when i make changes in the state & City drop down list,it will not done.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gr = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    LinkButton lu = new LinkButton();
    lu = (LinkButton)gr.FindControl("l2");
    HiddenField1.Value = lu.CommandArgument.ToString();
    DAL.DAL_EmpReg obj = new DAL.DAL_EmpReg();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = obj.fetchDataById(HiddenField1.Value.ToString());
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtname.Text=dt.Rows[0]["empName"].ToString();
        txtemail.Text = dt.Rows[0]["empEmail"].ToString();
        txtcontactno.Text = dt.Rows[0]["empContactNo"].ToString();
        txtdeg.Text = dt.Rows[0]["empDesination"].ToString();                
        txtsalary.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Empsal"].ToString();
        ddlstate.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["empState"].ToString();
        City(ddlstate.SelectedValue);
        ddlcity.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["empCity"].ToString();
        txtaddress.Text = dt.Rows[0]["empAddress"].ToString();                
    }            

    btnsubmit.Text = "Update";
}
```

Here state & City two different table.Grid view show the data from the view.City table have the foreign key reference of State table.

Comment: You have to do some programming to save the values in the database. You only show us how you put them (values) in the textboxes.

Comment: So which code I have to display.I appreciate your suggestion. @peer

Comment: the code excecuted to save the item in the database.

Comment: are you using any DataSource controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the below mentioned article. It has doj field that is filled in 3 day,month and year  dropdownlists on click of edit button inside gridview and it is updating properly. Hope this will resolve your problem 
**Bind,Save,Edit,Update,Cancel,Delete,Paging example in GridView in asp.net C#** 
http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/07/bindsaveeditupdatecanceldeletepaging.html